# Javascript: onload event not reaching for javascript's FileReader API

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create extract the signature of a file at the client level itself so as to positively determine its file type. Below is my file input object:

```
<input id="test1" type="file">
```

I wrote the following javascript code against it:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('test1');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log("file selected");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("loaded");
        var file_slice = gcUploadFile.slice(0,4);
        console.log(file_slice);
        var arr_buffer = reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file_slice);
        console.log(arr_buffer);
    }
});
```

Check out [the fiddle for the above](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5wfg8/).

The trouble I am having is that my code does not even enters the `onload` fucntion.

What am i doing wrong?

**Note:** I am coding only using plain javascript but i am open to use Google Closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would it reach the onload handler, nothing is ever read by the FileReader.

You have to pass the file to the fileReader by reading it as something

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('test1');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log("file selected");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("loaded");
        var file_slice = gcUploadFile.slice(0,4);
        console.log(file_slice);
        var arr_buffer = reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file_slice);
        console.log(arr_buffer);
    }

    reader.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0]);

});
```